# Page initialization patterns with ASP.NET MVC and MVVM like knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, mvvm, initialization, knockout.js

When creating an interactive form or other kind of web page, there are a couple of options with knockoutjs. One could create a strongly-typed view and pass a model to it from a controller. On the other hand, one could just as easily start with a plain old html document, and have it initialize itself by calling action methods (JsonResult or otherwise) *after* the initial load.

Also when starting out the page as an MVC view, you could use HtmlHelpers along with plain old html markup to initialize the view. Another option is to serialize the model state as json to a hidden field, and use that to initialize the view.

In my experience, during first load, there can be a delay when you let ko initialize the view. Whether you construct a viewmodel by passing json from a serialized hidden field, or rely on it to invoke various services to load the data, there is a moment before the page is "ready". These kinds of delays can be avoided by initializing the page with HtmlHelpers, etc, but such initialization could also incur additional costs (extra initialization logic in the controller, default content in the views, etc).

Which way of initializing a page is the most MVVM? Is it a bad idea to use HtmlHelpers in the views, or to use cshtml at all? If not, where do you draw the line between view and viewmodel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The most MVVM" is a hard question to answer, especially considering that we are already mixing patterns with MVC and Knockout.

I would think that letting Knockout do all the work of initilization would be "the most MVVM", but rigid adherance to a pattern when you are having issues is not a good idea. If KO setting values after the DOM is ready causes problems that you can fix by letting the `HtmlHelpers` initialize the page, then **do what works**. Since the `HtmlHelpers` will let you set the `data-bind` attributes at the same time, this feels like a good solution, and I have done this before with good results.

I would say that storing JSON in a hidden field is not a good idea though. You can directly encode your model into JSON by using this in your javascript:

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

This is a good solution since the page starts out with the data your controller sends it, without needing a second request.

You may have to think about what trade-offs you want to make. If you want purity and no code duplication, you might have to accept the issue of KO taking a little time to initialize the page. If you want a perfect User Experience, you may have to sacrifice a little purity.

Comment: I like your answer, except the part about using razor to generate script. Ideally we'd like to be able to pull the JS out into a static file, and serializing to a hidden field, some data-* attribute, or somewhere else in the view is our current approach. Though I suppose we could keep the vm in a separate file, and just construct it using some razor-dependent script. Is this what you do?

Comment: There is no reason the viewmodel definition could not be in its own file. Using the snippet I posted (and using a script tag to link to your JS file), you would then just call `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(initialData))`, and it should fire up correctly.

Comment: @danludwig Sorry, I only skimmed your last sentence the first time, this is obviously what you were suggesting. Yes, it is what I have done in the past. It worked well for me.

Comment: Right, so just 2 lines of razor-dependent script, I get ya. One last clarification: why is putting the JSON in a hidden field a bad idea? To keep it out of POSTS when you serialize the whole form? What about serializing it to a data-* attribute somewhere, do you think that's a bad idea too, and why?

Comment: @danludwig Your cluttering the DOM, and you still need a line in javascript to pull the data so you aren't saving yourself any work. It's not like a serious crime or anything, I just think its inefficient.

Comment: Excellent answer Tyrsius. I also initialize my initial data with @Html.Raw - I pass it directly into my top-level view model constructor in my document ready function. Something which has speeded up my context quite a lot on subsequent page loads is to store all of my generic reference data (things which are not specific to particular view models, like lists of occupations for selects) in a big object literal pulled down as a separate script from a controller action which then gets cached by the browser.